# React - prevent onClick from firing parent's bootstrap event

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, events

So I have a Bootstrap *( not react-bootstrap, just plain bootstrap)* panel group in my React app, each panel opens up on clicking the panel heading. I also have a small `span` component inside the panel-heading, with an `onClick` handler attached to it.

My problem is, whenever I click on the `span`, the panel heading click is also triggered and the panel is closed/opened.

I tried the following things inside my `onClick` handler, but none of them prevented the event from bubbling up to the panel heading:
`ev.stopPropagation()`
`ev.preventDefault()`
`ev.nativeEvent.stopPropagation()`
`ev.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()`

The bootstrap clicks work based on `data-toggle` attributes.

**UPDATE** Code snippet reproducing the issue: https://codepen.io/danegit/pen/YOjdeN

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Question updated. Thank you!

Comment: It is because the data-toggle attribute is in the parent div where the span with onclick event is included. How about transferring the data-toggle to another element? Like in the button above the span element. Or do you want the data-toggle to stay on the parent div and wanted to know how to stop event for opening the collapsible div?

Comment: @GioRodriguez Yes I want to open the panel upon clicking anywhere in the div except the span. I'm not understanding why `stopPropagation()` is not stopping it. Maybe the direction of event listener of bootstrap is different